# SQLite Use variable in Insert Query

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to make a python SQLite GPA Calculator project, where I want to be able to use user input and insert the values given by the user into an SQLite Table. I already figured out how to INSERT QUERY, but I want to know how to use variables in python3 in SQLite Inserts. I can't seem to find any solutions that are applicable to my code, so help would be much appreciated!

```
import sqlite3

try:
    sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect("SQLite_Python_Test.db")
    sqlite_query_create_table = '''CREATE TABLE gpa_calc_users_test(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        username TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        password TEXT NOT NULL,
        gpa_sem1 REAL,
        gpa_sem2 REAL);'''

    sqlite_query_insert = '''
    INSERT INTO gpa_calc_users_test
        (id, username, password, gpa_sem1, gpa_sem2)
        VALUES
        (1,'test', 'blablabla', 3.7, 3.5 )
    '''

    cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
    sqliteConnection.commit()
    print("Connected to sqlite Successfully")


    cursor.execute(sqlite_query_create_table)
    sqliteConnection.commit()
    print("Table created Successfully")

    cursor.execute(sqlite_query_insert)
    sqliteConnection.commit()
    print("Query inserted Successfully")
    cursor.close()

except sqlite3.Error as error:
    print("Error while creating a table")

finally:
    if(sqliteConnection):
        sqliteConnection.close()
        print("SQLite connection closed")
```

Comment: This feature is called parameter substitution and is covered in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sqlite3.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may use a prepared statement for your insert, and then bind variables to it:

```
params = (1, 'test', 'blablabla', 3.7, 3.5,)
sql = """INSERT INTO gpa_calc_users_test
         (id, username, password, gpa_sem1, gpa_sem2)
         VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"""
cursor.execute(sql, params)
```